# Error using parse cloud code that allows users to essentially like each others profile.

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

So I am building an app, and in this app users will be able to go to each others' profile, and essentially like their profile. I am calling these likes compliments. This requires the current user to be able to access the selected users information to update the compliment count. So in order to implement this I am using Parse.com's cloud code.

My code looks like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("complimentCounter", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var user = new User();

    var user.id = request.params.userId;
    var increment = request.params.increment;

    user.increment = ("complimentsValue", increment);
    user.save(null, {
            success: function(user) {
            response.success(true);
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
            response.error("Could not compliment.");
            }
    });
});
```

However when I run it I get the error "Unexpected token . in main.js:8", and when I take that "." out it only returns the error of the function and not the success. Can someone please guide me in the right direction, and let me know what the issue is here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `increment()` function is [documented here](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#increment).

The correct way to call it is:

```
// increment by 1
user.increment("keyName");
// increment by a number in a variable (yes you can use negative numbers too)
var increaseAmount = -5;
user.increment("keyName", increaseAmount);
```

You're reading a value, which seems to mean you want to increase the count by more than one, so the 2nd syntax is what you want.

Unfortunately you're calling it incorrectly, just take the `=` out of your line so it reads as follows:

```
user.increment("complimentsValue", increment);
```